# Copying Excel's tables to Word in office Apps JavaScript API

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-addins

Whole sheet copying to word after opening it,Fetched data from Excel and copy to word Like **OLE** connection in Excel-Add-ins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at following link, It might be useful in your case

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/037b999f-6deb-44ad-9ebf-d9d4bdca7bfe/copy-the-contents-of-excel-to-word-using-appjavascript?forum=appsforoffice